# jQuery object not parsable as HTML

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I have an ajax call returning various database fields one-by-one in a for loop.  I'm able to test if the field is HTML by using:

```
for(i = 0; i < copyFromSchedule.length; i++) {
    temporaryString = $(this).attr("ows_"+copyFromSchedule[i]);
    if ($(temporaryString).html() == null)
        // Is not HTML...
    else
        // Is HTML, remove any anchors found in this string (<a name="XXX"></a>)
        $(temporaryString).find("a[name]").remove();
}
```

In the else statement (when the string is HTML), I'm trying to (unsuccessfully) remove all HTML anchors using the function above.

How do I manipulate the object as HTML through jQuery?

**Update**

On further inspection, I've realized the problem is different from what I initially thought.

My issue is I'm not able to manipulate the variable (temporaryString) as a jQuery object.  For example, the following will not affect the html of the object:

```
$(temporaryString).find("div").remove();
```

So, in theory if I have the following:

```
temporaryString = "<span>Span Content</span><div>DIV Content</div>";
$(temporaryString).find("div").remove();
```

I would assume 'temporaryString' should now equal:

```
<span>Span Content</span>
```

since the div is removed.

Is my logic wrong?  It doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: there is no such thing as an `else loop`

Comment: @Neal, just a typo.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: its ok ^_^ it happens to the best of us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your problem: In Javascript, **strings are immutable**, that means that they can't be changed. Unless you assign something different to the variable `temporaryString`, that variable isn't going to change.

When you run this code:

```
temporaryString = "<span>Span Content</span><div>DIV Content</div>";
$(temporaryString).find("div").remove();
```

This is what happens:

1. `"<span>Span Content</span><div>DIV Content</div>"` is assigned to `temporaryString`
2. `$(temporaryString)` runs, parsing `temporaryString` and creating a corresponding array-like object (the jQuery object) of html elements and returns it. `temporaryString` is left unchanged.
3. `.find("div")` runs, finds all div elements in the result of the above step and returns them. `temporaryString` is left unchanged.
4. `.remove()` runs, removing the elements returned by the previous step from the jQuery object. `temporaryString` is left unchanged.
5. The objects and elements created by `$(temporaryString).find("div").remove()` pass out of scope and are deleted by the garbage collector. `temporaryString` **has still not been changed.**

In short, if you don't do anything with the result of `$(temporaryString).find("div").remove()`, nothing happens.

If you want `temporaryString` to become `"<span>Span Content</span>"`, you need to assign the result of all the manipulations you've done to the jQuery object back into the `temporaryString` variable. The best way to do this is to create a `div` element, set it's contents to `temporaryString`, remove the desired elements, and assign the new contents of the `div` element back into `temporaryString` like this:

```
temporaryString = $("<div>").html(temporaryString).find("div").remove().end().html();
```

For your original question, you can try this:

```
for(i = 0; i < copyFromSchedule.length; i++) {
    temporaryString = $(this).attr("ows_"+copyFromSchedule[i]);
    if ($(temporaryString).html() == null)
        { /* Is not HTML... */ }
    else {
        // Is HTML, remove any anchors found in this string (<a name="XXX"></a>)
        temporaryString = $("<div>").html(temporaryString).find("a[name]").remove().end().html()
    }
}
```

Sorry for the long winded answer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  I figured the issue related to a non-changeable factor in the variable, and wound up creating a (much less elegant) solution.

Answer (score 0):

IF I understand correctly:

```
if ($(temporaryString).html() == null) {
    // Is not HTML...
}
else {
    $('a', temporaryString).remove(); //remove all anchor tags
}
```

Comment: I updated the code above: the 'else' statement includes the function to remove any anchors from the code.  The idea is that I'm cleaning up the HTML.

Comment: As I understand it, OP doesn't want to remove all HTML. Just HTML Anchors (`<a name="top"></a>`)

Comment: That works for all `<a>` tags (including hyperlinks, which I don't think the OP wants to remove.  Correct me if I'm wrong Eric.)

Comment: @Kyle `'a[name]'` and `'a'` are basically the same thing

Comment: @Neal, not if you're distinguishing between a hyperlink and a page anchor.

Comment: @Neal, I'm not saying you're wrong, just that I understand the OPs question differently.  I could be completely wrong here myself.

Comment: take <a>text_between_anchor</a>: <a> and </a> denote anchor, text_between_anchor represents hyperlink, is that what @Kyly mean.

Comment: What would you call it then?  I'm referring to `<a name="blah"></a>`, which can later be linked to like `<a href="#blah"></a>` (a link within a page), versus a hyperlink `<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>`

Comment: I'm not trying to argue, I just read the OPs question to distinguish between the two.

Comment: @Kyle, yes. Need OP's clarification.

Comment: @Kyle and @didxga, I'm referring to '<a name="blah"></a>' as an HTML anchor.  Is this not the correct term for it?

Comment: @Eric, do you want to keep hyperlinks `<a href="blah"></a>`?  If so, using `a` will remove those too.

Answer (score 0):

I find it easiest to add an string "HTML" to a wrapper element before testing with JQuery:

```
$('<div>').html(temporaryString).find('a[name]').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should be doing this instead if [all you want is just anchors](http://jsfiddle.net/Che7G/).

> $(temporaryString).find("a").remove();

but the thing is, what's in the temporarystring?
if it's just text then i think the easiest way is to use a hidden div and paste the html there and call the div to process using jquery.

i.e.

```
$("#hiddenDivId").html(myHtmlChunk);
$("#hiddenDivId").find("a").remove();

//then do whatever u want with the html and clear the hidden div
$("#hiddenDivId").html("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap up your `temporaryString` with some markup(ideally `div` with ad hoc id), then refer it as an jQuery DOM, you can then remove element within it.